# vue 2 how to update v-model if value is changed?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a few cards works like radio-button.

```
<div class="card">
    <input
       checked=""
       class="card__input"
       type="radio"
       v-model="templatePicked"
       :value="template.value"
       name="template"
       :id="template.id"
     >
    <label :for="template.id" class="card__label"></label
    <ui-select
       name="version"
       placeholder="Select a version"
       :keys="{ label: 'text', value: 'value' }"
       :options="templateVersions"
       v-model="template"
     ></ui-select>
</div>
```

So, when we click on select item (in ui-select) we update `id` and `value` for card radio button. The question is, how to update templatePicked? Because now it updates only when I click on radio button.

P.S
I use vue 2.2.6.
Select component: https://josephuspaye.github.io/Keen-UI/#/ui-select
It has `@change` event but I don't understand how to use it in my case.

P.S.S
It actually works perfect in vue 1.0.28, I used `:value.sync="ubuntu"` on  component.

Any help, please!

Comment: Hi maybe the @select event is useful for this, for example: @select="setTemplatePicked(template)", then within the method setTemplatePicked do the logic of the picked template.

Comment: @M.Suurland man you're right! It works now, thanks. You can write answer and I'll mark it as best. But why when I select another option in ui-select and radio button turn to unchecked?

Comment: try putting {{ templatePicked }} in your html, to see how the value changes of templatePicked, i guess you somewhere set it wrong

Comment: @M.Suurland yes, I fixed that. Please last question is, how to set default value to ui-select in my case? Because I can not just write the value in model or value because data is dynamic. But I want to set the first object.value in my templateVersions array.

Comment: You mean you want to add the first option (template) to templateVersions?

Comment: @M.Suurland No. I have array `templateVersions = [ { label: 'template_1', id: '1', 'value': 1 },  { label: 'template_2', id: '2', value: '2' } ];` So I want to set first label of the first object in templateVersions as a default value for ui-select.

Comment: To achieve this, the common way is to v-model to for example foo (data) and set foo to 'Hi' within your data instead of an empty ' ', and then have your options like you do now.

Comment: hmm, can't do this. I have to set v-model="template" for ui-select because I need to push selected value to `template`, so I can't set default value then

Answer (score 2):

You can listen to the @select event (when an item is selected) or for example @focus. See https://josephuspaye.github.io/Keen-UI/#/ui-select (events), for more options.

```
<ui-select
   name="version"
   placeholder="Select a version"
   :keys="{ label: 'text', value: 'value' }"
   :options="templateVersions"
   v-model="template"
   @select="setTemplatePicked(template)"
 ></ui-select>
```

Next add a method (for example setTemplatePicked) which sets the selected template.

Comment: A bit of additional explanation: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#once-and-sync-Modifiers-on-v-bind-removed

Comment: It works on click. But I noticed that if I select one option as default, how then get the data from template and set to templatePicked? Initially, when page is loaded